# How convert the image into binary (BLOB) before passing it as a paramater?

Tags: ng-file-upload

I am using the plugin provided [here](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) . I want to convert the image into binary formate before I pass it as a parameter to the service. How can I do the using this plugin? Is it possible?

Comment: Each image or File selected in the model is already a Blob, so there is no conversion needed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: if you want to convert it to byte array that's a different story but I doubt it would be useful in any scenario. Maybe describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks @danial. Your comments were useful.